# How to size an image to a table cell in Kramdown?

Tags: html, html-table, markdown, jekyll, kramdown

I'm building a Jekyll site and I believe it uses kramdown. My problem is that I'm having issues sizing an image in a table cell.

In the markdown file I'm trying to include an image, either a check mark or an X in the 3rd column. I can get the image to appear, but it doesn't scale down. It just appears really big.

```
| : 1st Column : | : 2nd Column : | : 3rd Column : |
| Sec A : | Para | ![Supported](/assets/images/check.png){: width="10"}|
| Sec B : | Para | X |
```

Any thoughts on how to do this? Or is there a better way to include a check and X?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using task list which gives a handy progress indicator of work which shown as a checkbox.